# Will everyone convert to be a Muslim before Qayamat?

Tags: conversion, day-of-judgement

There is a popular belief at my place, and in my extended family that by the Last day of Judgement or Qayamat, everyone on earth will be a Muslim.

I googled that up,but I couldn't find any such thing.

So, is it true..?

What does Qurán say about the increasing population of Muslims?

Comment: It's not true, in Quran surah al- waqiah, Allah talks about a few forerunners from the later generations.  This tells us that true believers will be few even though many people claim to follow Islam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

**Day of judgement will come when there will not be even single believer on the earth!!** If you read anything(from quran and hadees) regarding when the end day will come, you will find that all of that signs indicate that islam will be less followed, even one of the last signs include the quran will be lifted by Allah, all the written copies will be vanished, and all people who remember anything from it will forget it. And this will be by Allah.

**So, clearly its not the case that all people will be muslim, infact it will be reverse of it.**

> Al-Daarimi narrated saheeh isnaad (no. 3207) that ‘Abd-Allaah ibn
>   Mas’ood said: “**Recite the Qur’aan much before it is taken away**.” They
>   said, “**These Mus-hafs will be taken away**! What about that **which is
>   (memorized) in men’s hearts?” He said: “Something will come and take
>   it one night, and in the morning they will wake up without it. They
>   will forget the phrase ‘laa ilaaha ill-Allaah’ and they will start to
>   recite the sayings and poetry of the Jaahiliyyah.** That is when the
>   Word will be fulfilled against them.”

**I think** they might be pointing to a belief in islam that before judgement day, islam will become only religion in the  world for some time. And islam will rule the whole world. And most of the scholars say it will be after Allah will send the Essa/jesus in the time of mehdi and they will kill dajjal and all that. But that will be before judgement day, not JUST BEFORE... like many other signs which have already been fulfilled they were supposed to happen before judgement day, not JUST BEFORE judgement day. You might talk with some local scholar to clarify about this belief in your area. whether it is about just before judgement day or this happening mentioned in ahadees.

> Narrated AbuHurayrah: The Prophet (peace_be_upon_him) said: There is
>   no prophet between me and him, that is, Jesus (peace_be_upon_him). He
>   will descent (to the earth). When you see him, recognise him: a man of
>   medium height, reddish fair, wearing two light yellow garments,
>   looking as if drops were falling down from his head though it will not
>   be wet. He will fight the people for the cause of Islam. He will break
>   the cross, kill swine, and abolish jizyah. **Allah will perish all
>   religions except Islam.** He will destroy the Antichrist and will live
>   on the earth for forty years and then he will die. The Muslims will
>   pray over him. 
> (Book 37, Number 4310: Abu Dawud)

Read some sign of day of judgement [here](http://www.islamicfinder.org/articles/article.php?id=75) and some [here](http://www.inter-islam.org/faith/Majorsigns.html).

**Your second question about population increase is totally different question... I think it is better to ask separately. It has no link with first question.** for a quick reference i can point to some refs [here](http://www.almosleh.com/ar/index-en-show-17940.html) and [here](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=82154) , will post proper answer inshallah if you ask separately.

May Allah guide us all to the right path.

### Allah knows best

Comment: I guess you have misunderstood his second question ,he is not asking about family planning.JazakAllah for your answer.

Comment: @servant i might have, but still it does not seem related.

Comment: Interesting. But then this begs the question: When we get resurrected, and you are saying there wont be a single believer then.. how are the Muslims who were supposed to be kept as Muslims and believers? Also, why would such a great religion be "vanished"??

Comment: @Ahmedilyas this will be just before the buggle (صور) will be blown for the judgement day, Allah will take all believers from this world to make judgement day easy for them. This is what i understand and i have mentioned this in my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not true, according to islamic scholars, Allah will bring qayamath on the worst of people, and qayamath will not come, till there is a person in the world who is chanting Allah's name.

Comment: if you add your references, it would be good